# VMWare - Lower the size of a disk

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, disk-space-utilization

We need to lower the size of a VM disk, we have 2 disk in the Virtual Hardware of that virtual machine, one of them is 8TB but at the end, only 600gb is used.

Current configuration:
[image]

If we tried to put a lower disk size, at the settings of the VM, we get an error and don't change it.

Wanted configuration:
[image]

I know that only 600gb is used for real and no 8TB, but We need to make sure that the size of the disk will never reach more than 1TB for example.

I don't know if we can unregister the VM, create a new one and add the existing disks with new disk sizes to solve this or what we can do.

Regards,

We tried to use Thin Provision, but it still can't allow us to lower the disk size.

Guest OS is Windows Server 2019

Comment: Which guest OS? This *will* require shrinking the partition on the disk.

Comment: Also, your post is missing the actual images or links you wanted to include.

Comment: Hi Massimo, I added Guest OS information and fixed the images, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to actually shrink the disk, this is quite difficult; even if you manage to switch the virtual disk to thin provisioning, it will still be treated as a 8 TB disk and the guest OS can potentially fill it up later; also, the hypervisor doesn't have the same concept of "free space" as the guest OS: you could very well end up with a thin provisioned disk occupying 3 TB, if that space has been previously written to.

Since this is a data disk, a better approach would be to copy data around inside the guest OS and switch drive letters:

- Add another smaller disk to the VM
- Stop whatever service is using the data on the disk
- Copy all data from the large disk to the small disk  (you can use `robocopy` to preserve permissions, timestamps and everything else)
- Remove the large disk from the VM
- Change the drive letter of the new disk to be the same as the old disk
- Restart all services and/or the whole OS

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a VMware specific thing but generally speaking unless you've consciously gone out of your way to do so then you'll fine shrinking disk volumes to be considerably more complex than you'd like.

A couple of options.

- First shut down the VM completely and clone it to a thin-provisioned version - this is different from just trying to thin the original disk.
- Second Storage vMotion to a different datastore but request for it to be thinned as it does it, once thinned (if it works) just move it back to the original DS.
- just add a new thin disk to the VM and 'dd' the contents of the original disk to the new one.

Comment: I agree it's similar like hyperv it's nearly the same way/thing